# Flutter Dartdoc: How to Document State Objects in Statefull Widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, documentation, documentation-generation, dartdoc

This is a part of a project where i am building a clone of the Flickr App for educational purposes.

I am playing around for the first time with Dartdoc and Documentation concept in general, I managed to use Dartdoc and create a Doc folder with documentation for my project. However, for all my Stateful widgets, The widget itself has documented Properly however the state object (the object where I have my build methods, my initstate methods, and my state variables), I don't get any documentation for that, is that the default behavior or am I doing something wrong? I want to generate Documentation for this state object, the methods inside it, and the variables inside.

Apart From that, I am getting a couple of warnings, I will search further into those, and if can't manage to resolve them I will open a separate question.

Here is how I used Dartdoc:

**Dartdoc command**

[image: Dartdoc command]

**End of Dartdoc command**

[image: End of Dartdoc command]

**Generated Doc**

[image: Generated Doc]

**Generated Doc _ Methods**

[image: Generated Doc _ Methods]

Forgive me if my question is stupid, it is my first time ever working with documentation :D

***EDIT:*** A naive solution that I am doing, is that I moved most of my variables and methods to the widget object instead of my state object. Is this the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `State` class is private (`_FlickrCameraScreen`), so it will not generate public documentation.  If you want public documentation for it, you will need to rename it to `FlickrCameraScreenState`.  You can give it a private constructor if you need to restrict creation to your `FlickrCameraScreen` widget.